# The collection of $I(a,b,c)= \{(x,y) : x \in (a,b), y=c \}$ forms a basis for some topology on $\Bbb R^2$. Determine the closure of the disc $B^2$.

Tags: general-topology

> The collection of line segments $I(a,b,c)= \{(x,y) : x \in (a,b), y=c \}$ forms a basis for some topology on $\Bbb R^2$. Determine the closure of the disc $B^2$.

The closure is the smallest closed set containing $B^2$. Do I need to look at the complements of the basis elements or probably the unions of the basis elements since these are the closed sets w.r.t to the topology generated by the collection of line segments?

I somehow think I can cover the disc $B^2$ by starting from $I(-1,1,-1)$ and going up to $I(-1,1,1)$ so is the complement of the union of these the set I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This topology $,\tau',$ is the product of the standard topology in the first factor with the discrete topology in the second. Every open box in the standard topology $,\tau,$ on $\mathbb R^2$ is a union of elements of $\tau'$ so $\tau \subseteq \tau'.$

Now, the closure of $B^2$ in $\tau$ is closed in $\tau'$ also and so, $\overline {B^2}_{\tau'}\subseteq \{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}.$

Therefore, the only points that are in question are those on the circle $S^1.$

If $p=(0,1)$ then any horizontal open segment containing $p$ is an open set about $p$ disjoint from $B^2$ and so $(0,1)\notin \overline {B^2}_{\tau'}.$ The same argument applies to $p=(0,-1).$

On the other hand, if $p\in S^1$ is any other point, you can show by a strictly analogous argument, that $p\ \textit{is}$ in the closure.